# Using StringBuilder to fill in the blanks in a string

Tags: java

this method I tried to write is supposed to take in a string, and then an array of strings to be inserted into the original string at any `"_"` character, with an a/an before it, depending on what is appropriate.  It will be used if the strings to be inserted are variables, and I don't know if it should be a or an.  But it doesn't work.  For instance, if `theString` is just `"_"` and `array` is `{pineapple}`, then it prints `a pineapple_`.  If `theString` is `"I am holding _, which is not a fruit, like _"` and `array` is `{pineapple, apple}`, it prints `I am holding _, which is not a fruit, like a pinapple_`.  I have looked at it, but I am unable to find the problem.  I am not too sure how the `stringBuilder` class works, so the problem may stem from that.  Thanks for any help you can give me!

```
public static void printWithVar(String theString,  String[] array){
    int arrayPosition = 0;
    String insert;
    StringBuilder builder  = new StringBuilder(theString);
    for (int i = 0;i <= theString.length();i++){
        // if a "_" is found
        if (theString.substring(i).equals("_")){
            // if the first letter is a vowel
            if (array[arrayPosition].substring(0).equalsIgnoreCase("a") || array[arrayPosition].substring(0).equalsIgnoreCase("e") || array[arrayPosition].substring(0).equalsIgnoreCase("i") || array[arrayPosition].substring(0).equalsIgnoreCase("o") || array[arrayPosition].substring(0).equalsIgnoreCase("u")){
                builder.deleteCharAt(i);
                insert = "an " + array[arrayPosition];
            }
            // if just an "a"
            else{
                builder.deleteCharAt(i);
                insert = "a " + array[arrayPosition];
            }
            builder = new StringBuilder(theString = theString.substring(0, i) + insert + theString.substring(i));
            arrayPosition++;
            i += insert.length();

            // if there are no more strings to insert
            if (arrayPosition == array.length){
                break;// for loop searching for "_" characters
            }
        }// end if an "_" is found
    }// end loop
    System.out.println(builder.toString());
}// end printWithVar
```

Comment: A hint: instead of playing with `.substring().equals()`, just [`.split("_")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) the original string. You will only need to insert pieces of your replacement array between the split strings. Also, try naming your variables so that their purpose is apparent from the names; it does help writing cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

In response to the first comment (by 9000) I changed the code to this, and it now works.

```
public static void printWithVar(String theString,  String[] insertArray){
    String[] splitStrings = theString.split("_");
    String output = "";
    String insert;
    // loop until there are no mmore inserts
    for (int i = 0;i < insertArray.length;i++){
        // if an is appropriate 
        if (insertArray[i].substring(i).equalsIgnoreCase("a") || insertArray[i].substring(i).equalsIgnoreCase("e") || insertArray[i].substring(i).equalsIgnoreCase("i") || insertArray[i].substring(i).equalsIgnoreCase("o") || insertArray[i].substring(i).equalsIgnoreCase("u")){
            insert = "an " + insertArray[i];
        }
        // if a is appropriate
        else{
            insert = "a " + insertArray[i];
        }
        // add everything needed to the output string
        output = output + splitStrings[i] + insert;
    }// end the loop
    // print the resulting string
    System.out.println(output);
}// end printWithVar
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would accept an alternative solution, I would use `StringTokenizer`:

```
public static void printWithVar(String theString, String[] array) {
    final List<Character> vowels = Arrays.asList(new Character[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' });

    StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(theString, "_", true);
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;
    while (tok.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String token = tok.nextToken();
        if (token.equals("_")) {
            if (i >= array.length) {
                continue;
            }
            String replacement = array[i];
            if (vowels.contains(replacement.toLowerCase().charAt(0))) {
                result.append("an " + replacement);
            } else {
                result.append("a " + replacement);
            }
            i++;
        } else {
            result.append(token);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexOf instead which returns the position of the first occurrence of `"_"` or -1 if it isn't found. While `"_"` can be found use `.replace(...)` method to swap out `"_"` with the word from the string array `array[wordArrayPosition]`.

```
public static void printWithVar(String theString,  String[] array){
    int wordArrayPosition = 0;
    String[] vowels = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"};
    StringBuilder builder  = new StringBuilder(theString);

    int indexOfSymbol = builder.indexOf("_");
    while (indexOfSymbol != -1) {

        //Adding a or an to the word
        String word = null;
        if (Arrays.asList(vowels).contains(array[wordArrayPosition].charAt(0))){
            word = "an " +  array[wordArrayPosition];
        } else {
            word = "a " +  array[wordArrayPosition];
        }
        //Checking if the word need to be capitalized
        if ((indexOfSymbol == 0) || (builder.charAt(indexOfSymbol - 1) == '.')) {
            word = "A" + word.substring(1);
        }

        builder.replace(indexOfSymbol, indexOfSymbol + 1, word);
        wordArrayPosition += 1;
        indexOfSymbol = builder.indexOf("_");
    }
    System.out.println(builder.toString());
}
```